# Limits the number of characters in textarea, for Rails by Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, textarea

I'd like to limit the number of characters in `textarea`.

I found the following Javascript code works well for a plain HTML file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function DjCheckMaxlength(oInObj)
{
      var iMaxLen = parseInt(oInObj.getAttribute('maxlength'));
      var iCurLen = oInObj.value.length;

      if ( oInObj.getAttribute && iCurLen > iMaxLen )
      {
          oInObj.value = oInObj.value.substring(0, iMaxLen);
      }
} //@ END OF DjCheckMaxlength()
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" name="T1" size="20" maxlength="20" >
<br /><hr />
<textarea maxlength="10" onkeyup="return DjCheckMaxlength(this);"></textarea>
</body>
```

What's the best way to use it inside a Rails app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should work essentially the same.

```
<%= text_area 'comment', 'body', :onkeyup => "DjCheckMaxlength(this);", :maxlength => 30 %>
```

If you want to link externally:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "my-functions" %>
```

Would get a JS file from **public/javascripts/my-functions.js**

Comment: You might also want to add an onchange, onblur, or onclick... I'm thinking if someone right-clicks and hits paste, then there is no onkeyup event.

Comment: Actually, there's a script at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm to help capture the right-click event... might require some modification for your purpose, though

Answer (score 0):

You can [decode](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html) it to ascii and check the length.

Comment: I need to check and control the `maxlen` when the user types, instead of checking after the data is submitted.